# How to display anova p value in plotly box plot

Tags: python, plotly, static-analysis, anova

I have created box plot which looks like this.

[image]

Now I want to add anova p value for each crop. For example for crop `Mn24` I calculated p value manually this way.

```
from scipy.stats import f_oneway

control= [15.72,
15.3,
17.55,
15.67,
16.59,
16.33,
17.57,
9.64,
18.81,
19.21,
13.19,
15.23,
15.5,
17.62,
16.19,
16.87,
14.84,
16,
17.28,
16.21]

min_uvc = [ 14.19,
16.36,
18.48,
14.42,
17.21,
15.53,
13.87,
14.4,
12.82,
18.22,
16.16,
12.32,
17.3,
12.91,
13.95,
15.16,
18.72,
15.04,
14.23,
15.44]

min_uvc = [
    19.15,
16.8,
16.2,
14.71,
17.71,
17.25,
16,
17.55,
14.68,
14.01,
17.4,
16.12,
17,
16.23,
15.89,
15.67,
16.5,
18.15,
17.15,
17
]

f_oneway(control, min_uvc, min_uvc)
```

Result

```
F_onewayResult(statistic=0.6694852492816592, pvalue=0.5159512878772639)
```

I want to display the p value for each crop in box plot itself. Similar to this.

[image]

I checked plotly box plot documentation https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.box.html but did not find any help in it.
Any suggestion or guide for how to do this ?

Link to data - https://gist.github.com/karimkhanvi/9ae9b5e365401fa79815cbfbbac569e1

Data can be seen here

Comment: You can play with annotation to do that. If I have time tomorrow, I will help you out. You can change the word “Treatment” with your p value.

Comment: Thanks @Phoenix: Are you still ready to help